# How can I join two tables considering given intervals

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I'm trying to join two tables

```
WITH A AS (
(SELECT 'KIM' AS NAME,
       '20160503' AS DATE
FROM DUAL)
UNION
(SELECT 'LEE' AS NAME,
       '20160307' AS DATE
FROM DUAL)
UNION
(SELECT 'PARK' AS NAME,
       '20170728' AS DATE
FROM DUAL)
),

B AS (
(SELECT '20160227' AS INTERVAL,
        '1' AS NUM
FROM DUAL)
UNION
(SELECT '20160520' AS INTERVAL,
        '2' AS NUM
FROM DUAL)
UNION
(SELECT '20170825' AS INTERVAL,
        '3' AS NUM
FROM DUAL)
)
```

In this situation, I want to make records in A joined with B like below

**'KIM' '20160503' '20160227' '1'**

**'LEE' '20160307' '20160227 '1'**

**'PARK' '20170728' '20160520' '2'**

Most important thing is that table A doesn't change at all but table B changes depending on some situations.

So, I can't now use CASE in table A simply and I have to join table A with table B that changes.

In short, I want to join table A with table B considering intervals.

If you give me a proper advice, I really appreciate that.

(I'm using Oracle DBMS)

Comment: On what conditions are the tables joined? And don't use strings for date/times but an appropriate date/time type. Same goes analog for integers/numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you confused us a little by naming your date column `INTERVAL` :-) It seems this is supposed to be the start date for a period and you want to join each name with the related period, i.e. the last start date before the name's date.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` in combination with `FETCH FIRST ROW` for this:

```
WITH a AS 
(
  SELECT 'KIM' AS name, DATE '2016-05-03' AS dt FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LEE' AS name, DATE '2016-03-07' AS dt FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PARK' AS name, DATE '2017-07-28' AS dt FROM DUAL
)
, b AS
(
  SELECT DATE '2016-02-27' AS start_dt, 1 AS num FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-05-20' AS start_dt, 2 AS num FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-08-25' AS start_dt, 3 AS num FROM DUAL
)
select *
from a 
cross apply
(
  select *
  from b
  where b.start_dt <= a.dt
  order by b.start_dt desc
  fetch first row only
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db7f96b6ef82bfe985a9f894c2e30b82

Comment: I didn't know 'cross apply' and 'fetch'. I'm trying to be used to using those two things. Thank you